# Windows: XAMPP install folder ini file permission error, Access denied upon configuration save

Tags: windows, xampp

After installing XAMPP to Windows 10 (all default/recommended installation attributes), I now have an issue changing its configuration after opening it.

Error: Cannot create file "C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini".
Access is denied

Clicking Save to a change in Configuration of Control Panel:

[image]

This "Configuration of Control Panel" box opens after clicking the "Config" button at the top right of the running XAMPP app:

[image]

I've tried a suggestion to run the XAMPP app with Administrator (elevated) access… but that seems like a major security issue, considering I don't know exactly what XAMPP would or could do with my files that require that permission, whether intended by the people who run XAMPP or not.

I've tried re-installing to another folder, like to C:\Users\Me, or a sub-folder like Documents or a custom one, but I just got different permissions issues that I struggled to figure out.

If you know a solution that worked for you, that avoided running XAMPP with Admin privileges, please let me know. I've gone through a handful of seemingly-related questions here but they seem to be related to MySQL/PHP questions and not Windows file system permissions.

Comment: Problem: xampp-control.ini file somehow become 'read only'

Solution: 
1. Go to Xampp installation folder and locate xampp-control.ini file.
C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini
2. Delete xampp-control.ini file
3. Run the xampp application file xampp-control.exe, it will recreate the xampp-control.ini file with proper file permission.

Now your application should look good.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after noticing that the file already existed from apparently a past workaround I tried with running XAMPP as Admin... based on the permissions of the file being different than its parent folder. I discovered this by right-clicking the xampp folder or the xampp-control.ini file then selecting Properties and clicking the Security tab, then clicking into each attached user account's permissions.

So, my C:\xampp folder has these permissions: for Admin, basically full access; for my user account, Read, Execute, and Write.

[image: xampp folder permissions]

The xampp-control.ini file has only Admin permissions; my user account is not attached to it.

[image: xampp ini file permissions]

Adding my user account to the xampp-control.ini file's Security, and adding Write permission then allowed XAMPP's config panel to save my changes.

[image]

Note that I typed my username into the "Enter the object names to select" box, then clicked Check Names; this auto-populated my username reference (?), though I'm not sure how it would work if it finds multiple results. Then I could click OK to get back to the Permissions box to add "Modify" and "Write" for it. I'm completely OK giving my user account permission to modify and write to this file through the XAMPP app.

Now, that fixes that file for that scenario; now I'm wondering if there will be other permissions issues with other files, because I noticed some other files (that I checked randomly) don't all share the same permissions for my user account!

Maybe I should have instead modified the xampp folder's permissions recursively to give my user account Write and/or Modify access (I'm not sure of the difference, Windows permissions seem far more complicated to understand and use than Linux's and Mac's do).

I think the file permissions were all set by XAMPP during install; I don't know yet that expanding permissions on certain files will not create new problems...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after noticing that error, here is my solution

1. go to xampp installation folder on the c drive
   [Xampp Destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWJOe.png)
2. then find xammp control panel.exe
   [Xampp Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbH3w.png)
3. then right click and go to properties(or press ALT+ENTER)
   [Click Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyQY6.png)
4. then go to compatibility and enable **Run this program as an administrator**
   [Compatibility tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYRk3.png)

**Your Problem is now fixed**